# Bluetooth Low Energy Rssi Android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing an application where I have to connect to Bluetooth Low Energy device on Android 4.3.
I tried this to display the rssi in my app but It doesn't work

```
@Override
            public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                //final LeDeviceListAdapter deviceLe = new LeDeviceListAdapter(device, rssi, scanRecord);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device,rssi);
                        mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                });
```

my list adapter code is :

```
private class LeDeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mLeDevices;
    private LayoutInflater mInflator;

    public LeDeviceListAdapter() {
        super();
        mLeDevices = new ArrayList<>();
        mInflator = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
    }

    public void addDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (!mLeDevices.contains(device)) {
            mLeDevices.add(device);

        }
    }

    public BluetoothDevice getDevice(int position) {
        return mLeDevices.get(position);
    }

    public void clear() {
        mLeDevices.clear();
       // notifyDataSetChanged();
    }






    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mLeDevices.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return mLeDevices.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        // General ListView optimization code.
        if (view == null) {
            view = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.listitem_device,viewGroup, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.deviceAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
            viewHolder.deviceName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
           // viewHolder.signal = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_signal);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        BluetoothDevice device = mLeDevices.get(i);
        //final String rssi_s=device.getRssi();
        final String deviceName = device.getName();
       /* ScanResult rssi=null;
        final double rssi_s = rssi.getRssi();
        String rssiString = String.valueOf(rssi_s);*/
        //final String rssiString =getString(valueOf(rssi_s));
        if
            (deviceName != null && deviceName.length() > 0){
            viewHolder.deviceName.setText(deviceName);
           // viewHolder.signal.setText(rssiString);

        }
        else
            viewHolder.deviceName.setText(R.string.unknown_device);
            viewHolder.deviceAddress.setText(device.getAddress());




        return view;

    }
}


// Device scan callback.
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
        new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                //final LeDeviceListAdapter deviceLe = new LeDeviceListAdapter(device, rssi, scanRecord);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       // String rssi_signal=String.valueOf(rssi);


                        mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
                        mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                });
            }
        };

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView deviceName;
    TextView deviceAddress;
    //TextView signal;
}
```

Do you have any idea how I can display this ? 
do I still have to type this in my oncreate method?

```
mLeDeviceListAdapter=new LeDeviceListAdapter();
```

Comment: What isn't working? Are you not getting any scan results or is the device list adapter not showing the right thing? Please post the code for the list adapter.

Comment: My app can show the name and the Mac adress of the beacon but not the rssi,  I'm sure that something is missing in my code that's why I'm hoping for someone who have done this before to guide me please

Comment: Show your adapter code please.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is (1) that the adapter itself does not have a method for tracking the RSSI value and (2) your adapter's list item view has no way to show the RSSI value and the adapter it self does not have a method for tracking the RSSI value. Here are the problems in detail:

**Problem 1** The list adapter is not capable of tracking the RSSI value.

You are adding the device and RSSI value to the adapter with this call:

```
mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device,rssi);
```

BUT the adapter only has a method like this:

```
public void addDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
    if (!mLeDevices.contains(device)) {
        mLeDevices.add(device);

    }
}
```

As you can see the methods do not match. I would propose doing the following:
First create a new class that will hold both the BluetoothDevice and the RSSI value. Something like this:

```
private class LeScanRecord {
    public final BluetoothDevice device;
    public final int rssi;

    public LeScanRecord(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi) {
        this.device = device;
        this.rssi = rssi;
    }
}
```

Then change you adapter to accept track instances of the new class (note that this addressed **Problem 2** by filling in the text field with the RSSI value):

```
/**
 * Adapter for the scan record devices
 */
private class LeDeviceListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LeScanRecord >
{
    /**
     * View inflater
     */
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;

    public LeDeviceListAdapter ()
    {
        super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.listitem_device);
        inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
    }
    @Override
    public void add(LeScanRecord object)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < getCount(); i++)
        {
            if (getItem(i).device.equals(object.device))
            {
                return; // do not add duplicates
            }
        }
        super.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        // General ListView optimization code.
        if (view == null) {
            view = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.listitem_device,viewGroup, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.deviceAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
            viewHolder.deviceName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
            viewHolder.rssi= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_signal);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        LeScanRecord record = getItem(position);
        final String deviceName = record.device.getName();
        if (deviceName != null && deviceName.length() > 0){
            viewHolder.deviceName.setText(deviceName);

        }
        else {
            viewHolder.deviceName.setText(R.string.unknown_device);
        }
        viewHolder.deviceAddress.setText(record.device.getAddress());
        viewHolder.rssi.setText(Integer.valueOf(record.rssi));


        return view;
    }
}

static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView deviceName;
    public TextView deviceAddress;
    public TextView rssi;
}
```

The last thing to do is add instances of the scan record to the adapter. So change:

```
@Override
public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
    //final LeDeviceListAdapter deviceLe = new LeDeviceListAdapter(device, rssi, scanRecord);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device,rssi);
            mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
}
```

To:

```
@Override
public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mLeDeviceListAdapter.add(new LeScanRecord(device, rssi));
            mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What about the arraylist of devices?

Comment: The BaseAdapter class maintains its own array; no need to add your own.

Comment: I guess you forgot to add rssi in the argument of addDevice method, but when I did it, it showed me errors in the "contains" and "add" used in it, I think because Rssi is an integer and not a BluetoothDevice type that's why it does reject it, how did you succeded in running the app? something is missing definitely

Comment: Check my code again. I am not adding a bluetooth device to the adapter; I am adding a class that contains BOTH a bluetooth device AND the rssi. Please try to run my code. It should work now.